# Preventing Node Modules from Referencing Global Location

Tags: angular, typescript

Once after pulling the latest update from Git, I faced an issue using `ngx-material-timepicker` along with the `luxon` library.

(Please note, `ngx-material-timepicker` is not a new introduction to the project, it has been used for some time)

However, I'm encountering a module resolution error related to `luxon` when building the project.

[image]

When I checked the errors in each `.ts` file, I noticed that Luxon is referenced from the global TypeScript types directory.
(`AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\5.2\node_modules\@types`) and not from (`node_modules\@types`) within my project. This discrepancy is causing a module resolution error when building the project.

[image]

I copied `luxon` module from a global location and pasted it into my project's local `node_modules\@types` directory. issues are fixed up to a certain level and only this issue is occurring now.

```
./node_modules/ngx-material-timepicker/fesm2015/ngx-material-timepicker.js:8:0-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'luxon' in 'D:\erpweb\ososerp\Web\node_modules\ngx-material-timepicker\fesm2015'
```

Things I have tried so far,

1. Deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` from the project.
2. Executed `npm cache clean --force`.
3. Deleted the 'luxon' folder from the global TypeScript directory.
4. Ran `npm i` to reinstall dependencies.

How can I resolve this,

Answer (score 0):

I was abled to solve it by doing these steps,

```
npm install luxon moment
```

Then installed the required dev dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash @types/luxon
```